# Javascript Functions For Copying text from a UIWebView

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, ios5

I am in the process of trying to get some selected text from a UIWebView (iPhone) and then displaying it on a Text View.

The method that I am using is:

```
function getHighlightedString() {
    var text        = window.getSelection();
    selectedText    = text.anchorNode.textContent.substr(text.anchorOffset, text.focusOffset - text.anchorOffset);

}
```

The text is then fed to a `NSString` and then is used by the iPhone program.

The problem now is that I can get the selected text if the text is just a few words of a line **BUT** as soon as I select more than a paragraph (with the "< p >" tags included) the data comes out to be blank in the `NSString`.

How can I use the text that was selected in the paragraphs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fairly easy. I used this line of code:

```
    self.selectedString = [self.bookTextWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.getSelection().toString()"];
```